# How to better use repeat while loop for indexing and array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, while-loop, iteration

I want to randomly pick a KanjiCard struct item from a given array, add the property "kanji" to another temp array and perform a check, if the randomly picked struct.kanji is present in the `yetShowedArray` repeat the random pick until you find a struct which kanji is not present in `yetShowedArray` in order to use it

the actual repeat/while flow does not assure it happens.

```
//test for the not repeating run *************************************************************************************
        
        //check if the two array have the same number of items
        guard arrayToUse.count !=  yetShowedArray.count else {
            print("finished all the kanji")
            var matching = 0
            for element in arrayToUse {
                if yetShowedArray.contains(element.kanji!){
                    matching += 1
                }
            }
            print("matching kanji are : \(matching)")
            return
        }
        
        var random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayToUse.count)))

        //Instance
        kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]
        guard let kanjiToTrack = kanjiToShow.kanji else {
            print("kanjiToTrack is nil!!!")
            return
        }
        
        
        if yetShowedArray.contains(kanjiToTrack){
            print("contained")

            repeat {
                random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayToUse.count)))
                kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]

            } while yetShowedArray.contains(kanjiToTrack)
            print("refreshed random")

        }
        else {
            print("never used before")
        }
        
        yetShowedArray.append(kanjiToTrack)
        print(yetShowedArray)

        print("arrayToUse: \(arrayToUse.count) yetShowedArray: \(yetShowedArray.count)")
        
        //test for the not repeating run *************************************************************************************
```

SOLUTION

found after Anton Novoselov's answer

I changed the let `kanjiToTrack`  to a var then refreshed it inside the repeat loop

```
//Instance
        kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]
        guard var kanjiToTrack = kanjiToShow.kanji else {
            print("kanjiToTrack is nil!!!")
            return
        }
        
        
        if yetShowedArray.contains(kanjiToTrack){
            print("contained")

            repeat {
                random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayToUse.count)))
                kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]
                kanjiToTrack = kanjiToShow.kanji!
                
                
            } while yetShowedArray.contains(kanjiToTrack)
            
            print("refreshed random")

        }
        else {
            print("never used before")
        }
```

second solution

```
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayToUse.count)))

    //Instance
    kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]
    guard kanjiToShow.kanji != nil else {
        print("kanjiToTrack is nil!!!")
        return
    }
    
    arrayToUse.remove(at: random)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to refresh kanjiToTrack again inside repeat loop. As you said, it's struct - value type, so it seems you checking the same kanjiToTrack in while clause. Try this:

```
       repeat {
            random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayToUse.count)))
            kanjiToShow = arrayToUse[random]
            guard let kanjiToTrack = kanjiToShow.kanji else {return}


        } while yetShowedArray.contains(kanjiToTrack)
```

Comment: thanx for help, I had to modify your solution a bit, but you gave the right hint!, what do you think about my version? is the logic right for you?

Comment: As for me, it's ok. But maybe, it's better to pull out kanji card from arrayToUse? Take card, put it to yetShowedArray and remove from arrayToUse. In this case you don't need this loop which can take a lot cycles when almost all cards are inside yetShowedArray

Comment: Yes, seems good. And in this case you don't need to loop over. Just add and remove..

Comment: hi anton, could you help me understating the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022098/cannot-read-variable-from-entity-in-coredata-swift-3